# Beamer - Make line in align environment disappear

Tags: beamer, align, presentations

I have the following align environment:

```
\begin{align*}
        \text{RIR Gap} &= \text{Ex-ante} - \text{Equilibrium} \\
        \onslide<2->{
        &= \text{Nominal rate} - \text{Inflation} - \onslide<2>{\text{Equilibrium}} 
        }\onslide<3->{\fbox{\text{Equilibrium}}}
\end{align*}
```

I want it to look like this:
[image]
[image]
[image]

But right now it looks like this:
[image]
[image]
[image]

I tried putting \onslideonly@2 for the unboxed "Equilibrium" but it didn't work.

Comment: Try ```\only<2>``` instead of ```\onslide<2>```.

Comment: Thank you! That worked.